# iPhone: iPhoto like tile view for image browsing

Tags: iphone, ios4, photo-gallery, iphoto

In an iPhone application I want to create an UI that just look like iPhoto application where photos will be loaded like iPhoto's tile view.

I am planning to use UITableView To achieve this. 
How can I manage showing random sizes images just like iPhoto app shows in there gallery view?

Any library which will help to achieve it? Can you please provide code sample url's?

Answer (score 0):

Shiv you can try  [AQGridView](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/AQGridView) that may help you to achieve what you are looking for.

You can also wait for [IOS 6 and see](http://www.apple.com/ios/ios6/#photostreams) photo tools.

check out http://three20.info/ as well and may help you. Probably you may have hit [iPhone show photos/images sliding (like photo library and Facebook app)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777122/iphone-show-photos-images-sliding-like-photo-library-and-facebook-app) link. but be sure to check this [link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/11382-implementing-picture-gallery-like-iphone-have.html).

Hope this many things would help you; I tried to give answer in noon but it take me late and it's evening now.